# Mysql-WorkBench and YubiKey ssh-tunnel

Tags: ssh, mysql-workbench, ssh-tunnel, yubikey

My company uses a Yubikey to connect to the ssh consoles of the systems we manage. The Yubikey uses gpg to access the ssh private key on the card, but it fails to work through Mysql Workbench and we are forced to use SequelPro. How do we get Mysql WorkBench ssh authentication through the yubikey?

Fyi, I contacted Mysql community and YubiCo and neither had an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found that we could just bind the remote MySQL port, 3306, to a local port, like 400. Assuming you have ssh working already with the Yubikey, of course. This was developed on my Ubuntu 20.04 LTS desktop, but could just as easily work on MacOSX or other Linux distros.

ssh user@host -L 4000:localhost:3306

Then in Mysql WorkBench you make a localhost tcp connection on port 4000 and you are tunneling through the ssh connection.

[image: image of mysql-workbench connections list with standard tcp/ip connection to localhost:4000]